# jQuery datatables TypeError: b is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am facing with a error fired by Firebug when using a jquery datatables plugin
The table is like this:

```
                    <table id="dt_cursuri" class="table table-striped table-bordered dTableR">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-class="expand">Curs</th>
                                <th data-hide="phone,tablet" data-name="Assign">Domeniu</th>
                                <th>Tip</th>
                                <th>Data modif</th>
                                <th class="centered-cell">Actiuni</th>
                            </tr>                                   
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="dataTables_empty" colspan="6">Fetching data from server</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

The datatables initialization:

```
        var oTable;
        var responsiveHelper = undefined;
        var breakpointDefinition = {
            tablet: 1024,
            phone : 480
        };
        var oTable = $('#dt_cursuri');

        oTable = $('#dt_cursuri').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
            "sAjaxSource": "view/cursuri/server_side.php",
            autoWidth : false,
            "fnPreDrawCallback": function () {
                // Initialize the responsive datatables helper once.
                if (!responsiveHelper) {
                    responsiveHelper = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper(oTable, breakpointDefinition);
                }
            },
            "fnDrawCallback" : function (oSettings) {
                responsiveHelper.respond();
            }, 
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData ) {
                responsiveHelper.createExpandIcon(nRow);
            },                                         
            "aoColumns": [
                //{ "sClass": "center",  "bSortable": false, sWidth: '2%', "bVisible": false },
                { sWidth: '35%' },
                { sWidth: '25%' },
                { sWidth: '20%' },
                { sWidth: '10%' },
                { "sClass": "center", sWidth: '10%', "bSortable": false }
            ],              
            "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']]
        } );
```

The server side json file is working corectly. The same code is used in other tables that work perfect, but this one is not

Could someone help me?
The error is fired for this line from jquery.datatables.js:

```
!a.sLoadingRecords && (c && 'Loading...' === b.sLoadingRecords) && D(a, a, 'sZeroRecords', 'sLoadingRecords');
```

Answer (score 4):

I will answer this question on my own thanks to developers of jQuery Datatables. 
The problem was in the server side processing. When using diacritics the datatable is messing with the data so you have to actually control the diacritics with utf8_encode() php function